# Port scanners on local network

Tags: networking, security, port

I currently run several servers for video games using two computers on my home network. Recently, I started seeing some anomalous IP's trying and failing to connect to one of these servers. After looking into some of these IP's using https://www.iplocation.net/ip-lookup. It showed that some of these addresses are research companies scanning open ports, but that others are known to commit cyber-attacks. With this in mind, I have two questions: should I be worried about these scans happening on my network and if so, what can be done to minimize these scans? I can include more information on a list of these IP's and anything else relevant if it helps.
Thanks

Comment: Port scans are part-and-parcel of running any services exposed to the Internet.   If you do not know how to to judge the risk of these and how to mitigate them you should not be exposing your devices to the internet through port forwards or the like.    Other then partitioning your network so your game server is isolated (and running a firewall on the server if relevant), the only other things you can do are only allow connections from trusted IP address ranges (if that is appropriate) and ensure the server you are running is trustworthy.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can report these scans to abuse address for this IP. Abuse address is in whois database for these IP addresses.
2. You can block these IPs or ranges of IPs on your router, eventually on server.
3. Scans make some delay for networking so they are not expected from anywhere/anyone, shouldn't be done without prior acceptance.

Answer (score 0):

Get and configure the tool [fail2ban](https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban).

If an IP triggers the logs to much fail2ban can exclude this IP for a defined time by quite sophisticated rules.

Like this the reaction is faster than you can be and the success-level for the attackers shrinks. Also the server load (depending on the attack profile) can be reduced by this.

Depending on your target group of visitors, you also can exclude whole networks by server rules.

If you have account specific problems (fake- & spammer- registrations) you can use third party services that return a kind of trust level for the combination username, e-mail and IP.
This need not to be a payed service. Also the free ones have effective results as I can see on daily basis.